# jquery append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I searched around but couldn't find an answer to this. I was making a little card game, and I need the game to append some text if a certain card is created. Appending text works otherwise on click events, but not for this function. The function is triggered correctly, as the console logs and such fire. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
function ghostcheck() {
    if (hand[0][0] == 'ghost'){
    ghostpresent = true;
    console.log("It's a ghost!!");
    $("#infocard").append("<p>Oh no! A ghost! What would you like to do?<br><br></p>");
}
```

Thanks for any help on the matter!

Comment: Do you have an element with Id `infocard` ?

Comment: Unless you just made an error while copy pasting, you are missing a closing brace

Comment: Are you running the javascript `before` the html is echoed ? Or using `$(function () { ... })`, `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` or it's siblings ?

Comment: Ah, no, I missed while copy pasting... and yea, infocard is there. There are other events that append text to it, but they all work on click functions.. like, "click card - append options". This one doesn't seem to work... basically, when a new card is drawn, it checks to see if the card is a "ghost", then asks the player to deal with it by running that function. The console logs and everything work, just the append doesn't.

Hn, I tried $(document).ready(function () {... and it ran it immediately. I'll keep playing around with that. That might be it.

Comment: A link to jsfiddle or jsbin will be good :). then we can check whats happening..

Comment: I had append problem when I deal with <br> tag in append, I need to append separately for the br tag and other text, you may try it.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting an idea that the element you are trying to append some text is created dynamically.

You can use jQuery's live() event to handle such issue.

[Link here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Hope this helps..

Comment: Hey I'm reading through it, it might be helpful, but the element is not dynamically created... I'll try it out though!

Comment: Just to confirm that the element is reachable, try this out and see what gets logged out on the console..
`console.log($('#infoCard'));`
If the output is "undefined", I guess it will be because the element is unreachable..

Answer (score 0):

```
function ghostcheck() {
    if (hand[0][0] == 'ghost'){
        ghostpresent = true;
        console.log("It's a ghost!!");
        console.log("Is there InfoCard? ", $("#infocard").length > 0);
        $("#infocard").append("<p>Oh no! A ghost! What would you like to do?<br><br></p>");
    }
}
```

If you can see the "It's a ghost!!" and "Is there InfoCard? true" at the console,
that means appending text is working.

I think another event handler is resetting infoCard element after ghost check function appending see text.

Comment: It's a ghost!!
game.js:217 Is there InfoCard?  true

Dang : / I found a solution, but it's less elegant. Basically the user has to click before they get the message.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure a double check if the '#inforcard' is correctly spelled in your html.

My sugestion is to try:

```js
//declare this at the start
$infoCard = $('#infoCard');



function ghostcheck() {
  $infoCard.append('<p>Oh no! A ghost! What would you like to do?<br><br></p>');
}

ghostcheck();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infoCard">
  ghost
</div>
```

and see if that works

Comment: Hn, I gave it a shot... nada : / I did find a less elegant solution where the user needs to click before they get the new text.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. Sometimes -and i don't know why- you have to assign the element to a variable, and make sure you use this variable as a reference in all places.

```js
var infoCard = $("#infocard");

function ghostcheck() {
    if (hand[0][0] == 'ghost'){
    ghostpresent = true;
    console.log("It's a ghost!!");
    infoCard.append("<p>Oh no! A ghost! What would you like to do?<br><br></p>");
   }
}
```